# Подгрузка с помощью spl_autoload( ) только файлов '*.php'

Tags: php, autoload

Функции spl_autoload() в качестве параметра передается имя неизвестного класса, которое затем преобразуется в имя файла.  Для этого имя класса преобразуется в нижний регистр, и к нему по очереди добавляют­ся все зарегистрированные стандартные расширения, **сначала** **.inc**, а затем **.php**.

Добавить расширение можно при помощи функции spl_autoload_extensions, например:
spl_autoload_extensions(".ext").

Как удалить все "стандартные расширения" для "подгрузки", оставив ТОЛЬКО .php?

Comment: Насколько понял из доки, расширения не добавляются, а заменяются

Comment: Сделайте так: 

print_r(spl_autoload_extensions());

Выдаст: .inc, .php. То есть - ".inc" - есть "по умолчанию". Должен же быть способ его оттуда бахнуть :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, всё оказалось просто, все зарегистрированные расширения не добавляются, а просто заменяются, т.е. делаем:

`spl_autoload_extensions('.php');`

`print_r(spl_autoload_extensions()); // Остаётся только расширение .php`

(спасибо @etki)